# ZKP: Asymmetric encryption with confidential message and known hash

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm searching for a ZKP package that supports asymmetric encryption so I can implement the following scenario:

Carol encrypts message $m$ with Alice's public key and sends the ciphertext to Alice. Bob and Alice both know $\operatorname{hash}(m)$, but because $m$ is encrypted by Alice's public key Bob doesn't know $m$--only Alice knows $m$.

Here is the part that needs ZKP: Alice wants to prove to Bob that this ciphertext is actually the encryption of a message whose hash is $\operatorname{hash}(m)$.

In other words, I want to be able to prove that I have a value whose hash is equal to y = hash(a), and whose encrypted form is z = enc(a), but I don't want to reveal a.

I searched in ZKP packages thoroughly, but none of them can implement encryption, so I take it that ZKP isn't the solution.

Do any of the available packages support what I am trying to do?

Comment: With package do you mean "software package"? Because that kind of reference requests are off topic. However, asking for a name of such a scheme is not. Once you've got the right terms it is possible to do an internet search yourself...

Comment: yeah I mean a software package and I don't know such a thing exists or not.

Comment: I recommend looking for Zk-SNARK. Here is a library called jsnark https://github.com/akosba/jsnark. It has circuits for encryption. Could you specify what is the use case for the scenario in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to prove a statement like hash(a) = y, I would recommend you to use a generic  zero-knowledge protocols which proves the computation of a boolean circuit using a witness w like presented [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/163.pdf) and [here](https://acmccs.github.io/papers/p2087-amesA.pdf). The authors first paper even published a reference implementation of SHA256 on [github](https://github.com/Sobuno/ZKBoo). Even though it's not impossible to additionally prove a statement like z = enc(a), I would recommend you not to do that for several reasons:

- The performance will likely be poor due to the expected circuit size and depth.
- Considering the adversary model you want to be secure against and the algorithm you choose, it may be still possible to create attacks if you don't pay attention.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, just wrap the message (in your case - the $hash(m)$) with HMAC which is used for authentication.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC):

> In cryptography, an HMAC (sometimes expanded as either keyed-hash message authentication code or hash-based message authentication code) is a specific type of message authentication code (MAC) involving a cryptographic hash function and a secret cryptographic key. It may be used to simultaneously verify both the data integrity and the authentication of a message, as with any MAC

There are plenty of HMAC implementations so it will be easy to find a package suitable to your needs.

Comment: HMAC is used when we want to commit a value and at the same time prove that actually it's our own message.I guess U didn't get the problem right.In another word my problem is : I want to be able to prove that I have a value a which its hash is equal to y = hash(a) and its encrypted form is z = enc(a) but I don't want to reveal the a